# NestJS API Accept one OR other Type in request body

Tags: api, nestjs, class-validator

I have a create controller which applies rigorous validation to JSON data before doing CRUD in a PG database.
I'm trying to achieve Validation of ONE of multiple types.

**The controller route**

```
async create(@Body() newSheet: CreateSheetsDto) {
        
        return this.sheetService.create(newSheet);
    }
```

**The DTO**

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import {ValidateNested} from "class-validator";
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { BodyValidator} from "../validators/BodyValidator";

export class CreateSheetsDto {  })
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    @Type(() => BodyValidator)
    readonly body: BodyValidator;
}
```

There are several layers of JSON validation, on multiple sub-keys.
I tried using the OR operator in the @Type callback, rather intuitively. The result is not working

```
export class CreateSheetsDto { //test
    @ApiProperty({ type: BodyValidator || TypeTwoValidator })
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    @Type(() => BodyValidator || TypeTwoValidator)
    readonly body: BodyValidator | TypeTwoValidator;
}
```

I also tried using the union operator in the controller, and creating another DTO specific for another type, such as:

```
async create(@Body() newSheet: CreateSheetsDto | CreateSheetsTypeTwoDto) {
        
        return this.sheetService.create(newSheet);
    }
```

This also didn't work.
I don't think I'm approaching this right but I also can't find much information on this online, would there be any lead you could advise?

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the class-transformer package. You can archive that by defining a discriminator as described here: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#providing-more-than-one-type-option

Example:

```
export class Album {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  @Type(() => Photo, {
    discriminator: {
      property: '__type',
      subTypes: [
        { value: Landscape, name: 'landscape' },
        { value: Portrait, name: 'portrait' },
        { value: UnderWater, name: 'underwater' },
      ],
    },
  })
  topPhoto: Landscape | Portrait | UnderWater;
}
```